# Unable to connect with the configured development Web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am getting the subject message when trying to open a web page on my development machine in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 pro. I have just set this machine up and have moved several projects to it. One of the projects opens fine. The other gives this message when I try to View the page in browser. Both sites are set up the same in IIS. I have tried several of the suggested solutions such as deleting the .VS file and re-opening the solution, in Admin mode, and not.

Most of the solutions to the issue were posted several years ago, with older versions of VS and Windows. Has any one found a solution to this issue in the newer versions of VS and Windows?

Comment: "Both sites are set up the same in IIS" is impossible. If you do configure two sites with the same settings (like site bindings), then you effectively create conflicts and only one of them can work at a time. Before trying any solution, carefully review your IIS settings and edit the question to include those.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I only use this to verify functionality when working in VS so sites are never used at the same time. I moved another site over from my older machine and it works correctly.   All site use the default application pool.  I can open pages in two of them when using Visual Studio. The third gives the "Unable to connect message".